# Why are there sometimes holes in framers squares?

Tags: tools, framing

Sometimes I notice there's 0, 1, or 2 circular holes in framers square. I also hear "framers square" and "carpenters square" tossed around as if they're interchangeable terms - perhaps the hole has some sort of relationship or distinguishing aspect between these 2 tools (or maybe they're synonymous)?

What are the holes there for?

[image]

Comment: The hole you pointed out -- as far as I know -- is simply a balanced point used to hang it up with (on a pegboard or nail or whatever).

Comment: I had to drill my own hole to hang the thing up properly.

Comment: @gregmac, that's the answer, I would post it as such.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's for hanging on a peg-board hook, both in the store and in the shop. Generally placed close to a balance point.

Answer (score 4):

The hole in the framing square should be placed in the tongue (the shorter, thinner part) of the square, so that when hung the blade (the longer, thicker side) will hang plumb or vertical, and the blade will be level or horizontal. Thus the square can be used to check your construction for Plumb or Level.

Comment: Given that the tongue is 14x1.5 and the blade is 24x2, then, if the blade all the same thickness, and there aren't any other holes or anything to throw off the balance, then the balance hole should be at (24*2*1+14*1.5*9)/(24*2+1.5*14) = 3.434783 ~ 3+7/16".  Mine's at 3+1/2" and hangs about 1/4" in 24" out of plumb.  If you are trusting the hole, Flip your square and check its plumbness.

Answer (score 4):

If the hole is dead center, it is the center of a 2x4 framing post (which are actually 1½ inches wide) so the center is at 3/4ths of an inch.

As an example, you can place the hole over the marks made every 16" for framing posts and then mark both sides along the width of the tongue because it is the same width of a 2x4.